# Building a String with nested quotes

Tags: javascript, html, css, string

I need to add html(doesn't necessary need to be a span) that has a fixed size, fixed background color opacity, and a variable background color.  I tried this:

```
var tr = htmlDocument.getElementById(myId).tBodies[0].children;
tr[1].children[5].innerHTML = '<center><span ng-style="{'background-color': getColor(parseFloat(myArray[index]))}">' + myArray[index] + '</span></center>';
```

and I got:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The id works perfectly fine, so don't mind that.  I also do not know how to add the opacity(say 50%).

Comment: using angular attributes with innerHTML?

Comment: Your problem is the fact you have single quotes inside single quotes....

Comment: I'm a complete noob I don't know what that means

Comment: You need to look into CSS rules. Using `<center>` and inline styles is not necessary. Just add a class and a CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the inner single quotes and give it a style attribute:

```
tr[1].children[5].innerHTML = '<center><span style="opacity: 50%; font-size: 15px" ng-style="{\'background-color\': getColor(parseFloat(myArray[index]))}">' + myArray[index] + '</span></center>';
```

Comment: Ahh yes escape.  I'll try this, but before I do can you add in an opacity of 50% ?

Comment: And size 15 or something

Comment: I am not seeing the color

Comment: You should take a look at [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS) to style your elements. What does `getColor` do?

Comment: here is default return value: `return "#FF9800"`

Comment: do i need to escape again?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Chris G's answer. Also, with Angular, you normally don't use `innerHTML`. If you are a beginner to web development, maybe it's better to stick with vanilla JS and learn the basics before using huge frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, a lot cleaner:

```
var tr = htmlDocument.getElementById(myId).tBodies[0].children;

var ngStyle = {
  "background-color": getColor(parseFloat(myArray[index]))
};
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.setAttribute("ng-style", JSON.stringify(ngStyle));
span.innerHTML = myArray[index];

tr[1].children[5].innerHTML = "";
tr[1].children[5].insertBefore(span, null);
tr[1].children[5].style.textAlign = "center";
tr[i].children[5].style.opacity = 0.5;
```

Comment: I don't see the color, and it is inserting it next to the span that is already there.  I want to replace the span that is in that position.

Comment: Added a line that clears the cell before inserting the span. As for the color, that is provided by the `ng-style`, so if you don't see it, you need to check the rest of your code.